# Creating a Snowflake shape that contains text in shape

Tags: html, css, svg, html5-canvas, css-shapes

I'm trying to create a snowflake on my webpage for the winter season.

The first thing I tried was creating it with SVG:

[image]

```html
<h3>Koch Snowflake Frac</h3>
<svg viewBox="-5 -5 110 110" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <polyline stroke="cornflowerblue" stroke-width="2" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" points="55 5, 
                    60 10, 
                    65 10, 
                    65 15,
                    70 20,
                    75 20,
                    80 15,
                    85 20,
                    90 20,
                    85 25,
                    90 30,
                    80 30,
                    75 35,
                    80 40,
                    90 40,
                    85 45,
                    90 50,
                    85 50,
                    80 55,
                    75 50,
                    70 50,
                    65 55,
                    65 60,
                    60 60,
                    55 65,
                    50 60,
                    45 60,
                    45 55,
                    40 50,
                    35 50,
                    30 55,
                    25 50,
                    20 50,
                    25 45,
                    20 40,
                    30 40,
                    35 35,
                    30 30,
                    20 30,
                    25 25,
                    20 20,
                    25 20,
                    30 15,
                    35 20,
                    40 20,
                    45 15,
                    45 10,
                    50 10,
                    55 5" />
  <foreignObject x="0" y="0" requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <p>Here is a paragraph that requires word wrap</p>
    </body>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

I could not get the **<foreignObject>** to work and even if I did it's not supported in IE browsers.
There is no need to support old IE browsers, but I would like support in at least one of them.
Also minor detail at the top, the shape is not closed.

Then I tried creating a snowflake in it with CSS:

```css
.snowflake {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 10px solid cornflowerblue;
  top: 200px;
  left: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}
.snowflake:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid cornflowerblue;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: -20px;
}
.snowflake:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid cornflowerblue;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 20px;
}
.smallbranch {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid cornflowerblue;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 17px;
  box-shadow: -130px -5px 0px 0px cornflowerblue;
}
.smallbranch:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid cornflowerblue;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  top: -22px;
  left: -22px;
  box-shadow: 130px -5px 0px 0px cornflowerblue;
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid cornflowerblue;
  background-color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.circle:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid cornflowerblue;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  top: -52px;
  left: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.circle:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid cornflowerblue;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  top: 102px;
  left: 20px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.branch {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  border-right: 10px solid cornflowerblue;
  left: 50%;
  top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="snowflake">
  <div class="branch"></div>
  <div class="smallbranch"></div>
  <div class="circle">Text in here</div>
</div>
```

This was my best attempt with CSS.
Now here the text is displayed but its not on one line. My idea is to use this in a logo or for a button on the webpage. So I don't think I will need line wrap functionality on the shape, but it would be a plus if it had.

The shape I would like created:
[image]

**TL;DR**
What I would like is a snowflake with text in the middle of the shape.
I'm asking for a solution where the text could be any length and still be inside the shape.
**You don't have to create a shape that's exactly the same as what I have tried** as long as the shape is a snowflake with text in the center it's ok.  I don't know how long the text will be so the shape has to contain the text.

Comment: Why don't you just use an image for the background, then center the text?

Comment: because i want to contain the text within the shape.

Comment: If anyone wants to figure this out, here's a link to an SVG of a snowflake. I don't have the time unfortunately. http://jsfiddle.net/fm8nckkL/

Comment: As far as your first example, you would create the .svg file in a graphics program. Illustrator or Inkscape then export it.  I'm sure you could find some free illustrator/photoshop snowflake shapes on the web to use too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [Play with this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t9rg2q4v/)

This is actually a quite interesting question, and coming up with an answer was not easy.

The question asks to make a shape(in this case a snowflake), that would scale to fit the text inside of it. My first advice is to use an image, not try and create the shape with CSS. Images are much easier to make scale, and can have more detail then a CSS shape.

So, lets show how we can accomplish this.

First of all, since you want the element to scale to fit the font, we need to make the element `display:inline-block`. This will make it only be as wide as it's content, unlike `block` which would make it as wide as it's parent, and still be able to set the height(which you cannot do with `inline`).

Next, we need to make the element with a height the same as the width. Luckily, there is a trick in CSS that allows you to do just that. The padding of an element is calculated based on it's width, so if you set the padding-bottom(or padding-top) to 100%, it will have the same width as height.([See this excellent SO answer for further info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/how-to-maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-using-only-css)).

After this, it is just a matter of centering the text inside the snowflake, which may take a little playing with the values to fit your font-family.

If you want the jsfiddle with code:
[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld91bzm8/)

### [Full-Screen JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sp5crt1d/show)

### Tested in Chrome, FireFox, IE, and Safari. Minor adjustments may be needed for certain font-family's

```css
.snowflake{
    display:inline-block;
      background:url("http://i.imgur.com/4M9MH1Q.png") scroll no-repeat center/contain;
    }
/*This is for setting the height the same as the width, a 1:1 ratio. more info http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html#outer_wrap */
    .snowflake:after{
     content: "";
     display: block;
     padding-top: 100%;
    }
    .snowflake span{
        display:inline-block;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(110%);
            -ms-transform: translateY(110%);
                transform: translateY(110%);
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
       padding-top:20%;
      }
/*This part is ugly, but it is required to work in chrome or IE, you may have to change the char for different font types*/
 .snowflake span:before, .snowflake span:after{
     content:"aaa";
     visibility:hidden;
     opacity:0;
  }
```

```html
        Font-size 12pt:
    <div class="snowflake" style="font-size:12pt;">
      <span>It's Snowing!</span>
    </div>
    Font-size 24pt:
    <div class="snowflake" style="font-size:24pt;">
      <span>It's Snowing!</span>
    </div>
    Font-size 48pt:
    <div class="snowflake" style="font-size:48pt;">
      <span>It's Snowing!</span>
    </div>
```

### EDIT: This solution is prettier, but doesn't work in Chrome or IE

```css
.snowflake{
display:inline-block;
  background:url("http://i.imgur.com/4M9MH1Q.png") scroll no-repeat center/contain;
}
/*This is for setting the height the same as the width, a 1:1 ratio. more info http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html#outer_wrap */
.snowflake:after{
 content: "";
 display: block;
 padding-top: 100%;
}
.snowflake span{
  display:inline-block;
    transform: translateY(90%);
  padding:20%;
  }
```

```html
Font-size 12pt:
<div class="snowflake" style="font-size:12pt;">
  <span>It's Snowing!</span>
</div>
Font-size 24pt:
<div class="snowflake" style="font-size:24pt;">
  <span>It's Snowing!</span>
</div>
Font-size 48pt:
<div class="snowflake" style="font-size:48pt;">
  <span>It's Snowing!</span>
</div>
```

The main condition for this to work is:

**`.snowflake` must be `display:inline-block;`**

### [Full-Screen JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gksko2q4/show/)

Comment: The text on Chrome is off onto two lines when looking at this

Comment: @JacobGray nice solution :P Even if it is with wrapped text :P

Comment: @Persijn I have got it working most of the way in chrome, the problem is the text is overflowing the snowflake a bit http://jsfiddle.net/f6u72qjn/ I can fix that by adding padding, but since it needs to be scale-able, then I should be padding with a percentage as the value, which isn't working in chrome

Comment: @Persijn that doesn't scale the best, if you change the font-size to something larger it breaks. However, I came up with a (completely stupid) solution, so I am going to do a couple more tests then post it

Comment: @Persijn Fixed. Ugly, but fixed.

Answer (score 5):

My solution uses part SVG, part HTML/CSS to create the effect required.

I have used the `calc()` CSS3 function along with viewport based width/height units which then give it the responsiveness required.

It looks much better when the element is above 200px wide.

- [`calc()` Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)
- [Viewport Units Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

**The Code**

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
}
.container svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  background: white;
  left: 17.5vw;
  top: 17.5vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 10vw;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2vw;
  border: 20px solid black;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 920px) {
  p {
    font-size: 3vw;
    width: 12.5vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" width="50%">
    <polygon id="christmas-snowflake-icon" points="441.535,346.644 373.955,307.624 438.697,290.354 431.342,262.782 338.967,287.424
284.535,255.999 339.49,224.271 431.299,249.242 438.787,221.705 374.311,204.168 441.535,165.356 427.266,140.644 359.686,179.66
377.1,114.956 349.545,107.541 324.697,199.861 270.27,231.285 270.27,167.831 337.797,100.809 317.695,80.554 270.27,127.624
270.27,50 241.732,50 241.732,128.036 194.404,80.604 174.203,100.76 241.732,168.438 241.732,231.286 186.779,199.558
162.498,107.565 134.906,114.847 151.957,179.455 84.732,140.644 70.465,165.356 138.045,204.373 73.303,221.645 80.66,249.218
173.035,224.574 227.465,255.999 172.51,287.727 80.701,262.758 73.211,290.293 137.688,307.832 70.465,346.644 84.732,371.356
152.312,332.337 134.898,397.042 162.457,404.459 187.303,312.137 241.732,280.711 241.732,344.169 174.203,411.191
194.307,431.446 241.732,384.376 241.732,462 270.27,462 270.27,383.964 317.598,431.396 337.797,411.24 270.27,343.562
270.27,280.712 325.223,312.439 349.502,404.435 377.094,397.15 360.043,332.545 427.268,371.356 "></polygon>
  </svg>
  <p>This is some text Now</p>
</div>
```

### [CodePen](http://codepen.io/stewartside/pen/rOpgXg)

Answer (score 4):

Using `svg` i have managed to make an almost responsive solution

```css
.box{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}

.box:after{
    position:absolute;
    content:"Some text";
    width:20%;
    height:20%;
    padding:5%;
    font-size:100%;
    left:calc(50% - 15%);
    top:calc(50% - 19%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 99.999997 100" height="100%" width="100%">
     <g transform="translate(0,-952.36216)" id="layer1">
      <path id="path4701" d="m 23,959 5,-3 6,11 6,-11 6,0 -9,17 4,7 8,-14 7,13 4,-7 -7,-13 3,-5 7,13 6,-11 4,2 -6,11 12,0 3,5 -18,0 -4,8 16,0 -7,13 8,0.12 7,-13 6,0 -7,13 12,0 -0.12,6 -12,-0 5,11 -3,5 -9,-17 -8,0.12 8,14 -16,0 4,8 18,0 -3,5 -12,-0.06 6,11 -4,3 -6,-11 -7,13 -3,-5 7,-13 -4,-7 -7,14 -8,-14 -4,7 9,17 -6,0.12 -6,-11 -6,11 -4,-3 6,-11 -14,-0.12 3,-6 15,0.12 4,-8 -15,-0.063 7,-14 -8,0 -9,17 -3,-5 6,-11 -12,0 0,-6 12,-0.06 -7,-13 6,-0.12 7,13 8,0.06 -7,-13 15,0.06 -4,-8 -15,-0.06 -3,-5 14,-0.06 z" style="fill:#2ad4ff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"/>
     </g>
  </svg>
 </div>
```

Try re sizing in the following snippet,it stays almost responsive if width and height are increased equally

```css
.box{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    resize:both;
    border:2px solid;
    overflow:auto;
}

.box:after{
    position:absolute;
    content:"Some text";
    width:20%;
    height:20%;
    padding:5%;
    font-size:100%;
    left:calc(50% - 15%);
    top:calc(50% - 19%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 99.999997 100" height="100%" width="100%">
     <g transform="translate(0,-952.36216)" id="layer1">
      <path id="path4701" d="m 23,959 5,-3 6,11 6,-11 6,0 -9,17 4,7 8,-14 7,13 4,-7 -7,-13 3,-5 7,13 6,-11 4,2 -6,11 12,0 3,5 -18,0 -4,8 16,0 -7,13 8,0.12 7,-13 6,0 -7,13 12,0 -0.12,6 -12,-0 5,11 -3,5 -9,-17 -8,0.12 8,14 -16,0 4,8 18,0 -3,5 -12,-0.06 6,11 -4,3 -6,-11 -7,13 -3,-5 7,-13 -4,-7 -7,14 -8,-14 -4,7 9,17 -6,0.12 -6,-11 -6,11 -4,-3 6,-11 -14,-0.12 3,-6 15,0.12 4,-8 -15,-0.063 7,-14 -8,0 -9,17 -3,-5 6,-11 -12,0 0,-6 12,-0.06 -7,-13 6,-0.12 7,13 8,0.06 -7,-13 15,0.06 -4,-8 -15,-0.06 -3,-5 14,-0.06 z" style="fill:#2ad4ff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"/>
     </g>
  </svg>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Using Canvas:

The snowflake can also be created programmatically using HTML5 Canvas. Doing it programmatically allows for better control over the text and keeps it within the container at all times. I am certain that this method can be converted into its equivalent SVG version but am more comfortable with Canvas.

One disadvantage of using Canvas is that the output is not responsive. It becomes blurred (pixelated) when scaled. The only way to avoid it is to redraw the shape once again whenever there is a change to the text (or) dimensions etc.

---

#### Construction

The shape is actually comprised of three parts and they are as follows:

- Inner star with 6 spikes (the green colored star)
- The lines  (red colored)
- Outer star with 6 spikes (the blue colored star)

[image]

The stars are drawn using the same approach as [described in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729543/creating-a-new-spiky-label-with-24-or-above-point-burst/30892219#30892219). Basically we assign an inner and an outer radius to each of them, find points on the inner and outer circle and then connect them alternately to produce the star.

The lines are also drawn using a similar approach except that it has only one radius and the lines are drawn from the points on the (imaginary) inner circle of the green star to specified points on the circle.

**Calculation of dimensions:** Since the text has to be fit within the shape and the shape must expand to fit the text, the first step that needs to be done is to calculate the `width` that the text requires. This is done using `measureText().width`. The value that is obtained is set as the radius of the green star's inner circle (because the text has to remain within it).

Finally, since the outer blue star should look as though it is kind of clipped (not appear in full), `height` and `width` lesser than that of the blue star's outer radius is set and a `border-radius` is assigned to the canvas element.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  spikes = 6,
  step = Math.PI / spikes,
  rot; /* no. of spikes for the stars */

function drawSnowFlake(content, font) {

  ctx.font = font; /* font of the text */

  /* get width required to fit text and set radius of each star */
  var text = ctx.measureText(content);
  innerRadius = (text.width / 2) * 1.15; /* extra factor is to leave gap between text and shape */
  outerRadius = text.width;

  /* set center point for the individual parts of the shape */
  x = leftOffset = outerRadius * 1.5;
  y = topOffset = outerRadius * 1.5;

  /* canvas height and width should be set same as the largest star for clip */
  canvas.height = outerRadius * 3;
  canvas.width = outerRadius * 3;

  /* default settings */
  rot = Math.PI / 2 * 3;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 15; /* thickness of the lines */
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue'; /* color of the lines */
  ctx.font = font; /* font of the text */

  /* create the inner star */

  ctx.moveTo(leftOffset, topOffset - outerRadius)
  for (i = 0; i < spikes; i++) {
    x = leftOffset + Math.cos(rot) * outerRadius;
    y = topOffset + Math.sin(rot) * outerRadius;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    rot += step;

    x = leftOffset + Math.cos(rot) * innerRadius;
    y = topOffset + Math.sin(rot) * innerRadius;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    rot += step;
  }
  ctx.lineTo(leftOffset, topOffset - outerRadius);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();

  /* draws the outer star */
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(leftOffset, topOffset - (outerRadius * 1.725));
  for (i = 0; i < spikes; i++) {
    x = leftOffset + Math.cos(rot) * (outerRadius * 1.725);
    y = topOffset + Math.sin(rot) * (outerRadius * 1.725);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y)
    rot += step

    x = leftOffset + Math.cos(rot) * (outerRadius * 1.15);
    y = topOffset + Math.sin(rot) * (outerRadius * 1.15);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    rot += step;
  }
  ctx.lineTo(leftOffset, topOffset - (outerRadius * 1.725));
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();

  /* draws the lines from the stars */
  rot = Math.PI / 3;
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (i = 0; i < spikes; i++) {
    x = leftOffset + Math.cos(rot) * innerRadius;
    y = topOffset + Math.sin(rot) * innerRadius;
    x2 = leftOffset + Math.cos(rot) * (outerRadius * 1.5);
    y2 = topOffset + Math.sin(rot) * (outerRadius * 1.5);
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
    rot += 2 * Math.PI / spikes;
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();

  /* add text and position it */
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.fillText(content, leftOffset, topOffset);
}

document.getElementById('draw').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var input = document.getElementById('content').value;
  var fontsize = document.getElementById('fontsize').value;
  var fontname = document.getElementById('fontname').value;
  drawSnowFlake(input, fontsize + "px " + fontname);
});

drawSnowFlake("TEXT HERE", "16px Arial");
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
canvas {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='controls'>
  <input id='content' type='textbox' value='TEXT HERE' />
  <select id='fontsize'>
    <option value='10'>10px</option>
    <option value='12'>12px</option>
    <option value='14'>14px</option>
    <option value='16' selected>16px</option>
  </select>
  <select id='fontname'>
    <option value='Arial' selected>Arial</option>
    <option value='Verdana'>Verdana</option>
    <option value='Courier'>Courier</option>
  </select>
  <button id='draw'>Draw</button>
</div>
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

---

**With Text Wrap and Bevelled Edges:**

Here is a more complex demo which also supports wrapping of the text into multiple lines if content exceeds a certain width. The below is what this snippet will do:

- If the size required for the text is less than max-width, shrink the shape
- If the size required for the text (height or width) is more than max-width, split the text into multiple lines, expand the shape to fit the text in center

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  spikes = 6,
  /* no. of spikes for the stars */
  step = Math.PI / spikes,
  rot, maxWidth = 100,
  lineHeight = 20;

function drawSnowFlake(content, font) {

  ctx.font = font; /* font of the text */

  /* get width & height required to fit text and set radius of each star */
  var text = ctx.measureText(content);
  var width = text.width;
  var height = splitText(ctx, content, maxWidth, lineHeight);

  /* decide which among height & width should be used for radius */
  if (width < maxWidth && height < maxWidth) {
    innerRadius = (width / 2) * 1.15; /* extra factor is to leave gap between text and shape */
    outerRadius = width;
  } else if (width > maxWidth && height < maxWidth) {
    innerRadius = (maxWidth / 2) * 1.15; /* extra factor is to leave gap between text and shape */
    outerRadius = maxWidth;
  } else {
    innerRadius = (height / 2) * 1.15; /* extra factor is to leave gap between text and shape */
    outerRadius = height;
  }

  /* set center point for the individual parts of the shape */
  x = leftOffset = outerRadius * 1.5;
  y = topOffset = outerRadius * 1.5;

  /* canvas height and width should be set same as the largest star for clip */
  canvas.height = outerRadius * 3;
  canvas.width = outerRadius * 3;

  /* default settings */
  rot = Math.PI / 2 * 3;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 15; /* thickness of the lines */
  ctx.lineJoin = 'bevel';
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue'; /* color of the lines */
  ctx.font = font; /* font of the text */

  /* create the inner star */
  ctx.moveTo(leftOffset, topOffset - outerRadius)
  for (i = 0; i < spikes; i++) {
    x = leftOffset + Math.cos(rot) * outerRadius;
    y = topOffset + Math.sin(rot) * outerRadius;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    rot += step;

    x = leftOffset + Math.cos(rot) * innerRadius;
    y = topOffset + Math.sin(rot) * innerRadius;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    rot += step;
  }
  ctx.lineTo(leftOffset, topOffset - outerRadius);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();

  /* draws the outer star */
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(leftOffset, topOffset - (outerRadius * 1.725));
  for (i = 0; i < spikes; i++) {
    x = leftOffset + Math.cos(rot) * (outerRadius * 1.725);
    y = topOffset + Math.sin(rot) * (outerRadius * 1.725);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y)
    rot += step

    x = leftOffset + Math.cos(rot) * (outerRadius * 1.15);
    y = topOffset + Math.sin(rot) * (outerRadius * 1.15);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    rot += step;
  }
  ctx.lineTo(leftOffset, topOffset - (outerRadius * 1.725));
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();

  /* draws the lines from the stars */
  rot = Math.PI / 3;
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (i = 0; i < spikes; i++) {
    x = leftOffset + Math.cos(rot) * innerRadius;
    y = topOffset + Math.sin(rot) * innerRadius;
    x2 = leftOffset + Math.cos(rot) * (outerRadius * 1.5);
    y2 = topOffset + Math.sin(rot) * (outerRadius * 1.5);
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
    rot += 2 * Math.PI / spikes;
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();

  /* add text and position it */
  wrapText(ctx, content, leftOffset, (topOffset - ((height - lineHeight) / 2)), maxWidth, lineHeight);
}

document.getElementById('draw').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var input = document.getElementById('content').value;
  var fontsize = document.getElementById('fontsize').value;
  var fontname = document.getElementById('fontname').value;
  drawSnowFlake(input, fontsize + "px " + fontname);
});

/* split text into lines based on width and calculate required height */

function splitText(context, text, maxWidth, lineHeight) {
  var words = text.split(' ');
  var line = '',
    height = lineHeight;
  for (var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
    var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
    var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
    var testWidth = metrics.width;
    if (testWidth > maxWidth && n > 0) {
      line = words[n] + ' ';
      height += lineHeight;
    } else {
      line = testLine;
    }
  }
  return height;
}

/* source from http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-wrap-text-tutorial/ */
function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight) {
  var words = text.split(' ');
  var line = '';
  context.textBaseline = "middle";
  context.textAlign = "center";

  var topOffset = x;

  for (var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
    var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
    var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
    var testWidth = metrics.width;
    if (testWidth > maxWidth && n > 0) {
      context.fillText(line, x, y);
      line = words[n] + ' ';
      y += lineHeight;
    } else {
      line = testLine;
    }
  }
  context.fillText(line, x, y);
}

drawSnowFlake('CSS SHAPES, SVG, CANVAS DESIGNS ROCK', "16px Arial");
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
canvas {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='controls'>
  <input id='content' type='textbox' value='CSS SHAPES, SVG, CANVAS DESIGNS ROCK' />
  <select id='fontsize'>
    <option value='10'>10px</option>
    <option value='12'>12px</option>
    <option value='14'>14px</option>
    <option value='16' selected>16px</option>
  </select>
  <select id='fontname'>
    <option value='Arial' selected>Arial</option>
    <option value='Verdana'>Verdana</option>
    <option value='Courier'>Courier</option>
  </select>
  <button id='draw'>Draw</button>
</div>
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

[image]

Comment: **Note:** I had checked with OP on whether a Canvas answer is acceptable or not before posting the answer.

Comment: Its scallable with the text size, and the container scales to. No problem with this solution :P

Answer (score 2):

The OP wanted the snowflake to scale to fit the size of the text.  Most of the other answers are doing it the other way around.

Here's the simplest solution I could come up width.  It is mostly just HTML and SVG with a tiny snippet of JS.  This is required because I don't believe it is possible to have an SVG scale to fit a parent that doesn't have an explicit size.

Change the text content or the CSS style of the inner `<div>` to your heart's content and the SVG snowflake will scale to match.

You could almost certainly do away with the JS if you were happy to use a bitmap background image instead of an SVG.

```js
$().ready(function() {
  divWidth = $(".snowflake div").outerWidth();
  $(".snowflake svg").css("width", divWidth + "px");
});
```

```css
.snowflake
{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.snowflake svg
{
  position: absolute;
  fill: #eef;
}

.snowflake DIV
{
  position: absolute;
  padding: 100px;
  font: 30pt sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="snowflake">

  <svg viewBox="2 0 32 36">
    <path d="M33.212,26.16l-3.054-1.764l1.84-1.062c0.238-0.139,0.32-0.441,0.184-0.684c-0.14-0.238-0.445-0.322-0.684-0.183 L29.16,23.82l-2.32-1.34l4.729-2.73c0.239-0.139,0.321-0.441,0.184-0.684c-0.139-0.238-0.445-0.322-0.684-0.183l-5.23,3.019 l-3.619-2.09l4.352-1.918l-4.354-1.919l3.619-2.091l5.231,3.021c0.079,0.047,0.165,0.067,0.25,0.067 c0.174,0,0.342-0.091,0.435-0.25c0.139-0.239,0.057-0.546-0.184-0.683l-4.731-2.732l2.32-1.34L31.5,13.32 c0.079,0.046,0.165,0.066,0.25,0.066c0.173,0,0.341-0.09,0.435-0.25c0.138-0.238,0.056-0.545-0.184-0.682L30.16,11.39l3.052-1.762 c0.239-0.139,0.32-0.443,0.184-0.684c-0.14-0.238-0.446-0.322-0.684-0.184l-3.051,1.763L29.66,8.401c0-0.275-0.225-0.5-0.5-0.5 c-0.276,0-0.5,0.225-0.5,0.5l0.001,2.699l-2.32,1.34l0.001-5.46c0-0.276-0.224-0.5-0.5-0.5c-0.275,0-0.5,0.224-0.5,0.5 l-0.001,6.037l-3.619,2.09l0.515-4.728l-3.838,2.81V9.008l5.229-3.021c0.238-0.138,0.32-0.443,0.184-0.684 c-0.14-0.238-0.445-0.321-0.684-0.182l-4.729,2.73V5.173l2.339-1.352c0.239-0.138,0.321-0.443,0.184-0.684 c-0.14-0.238-0.445-0.322-0.684-0.182L18.399,4.02V0.5c0-0.276-0.224-0.5-0.5-0.5s-0.5,0.224-0.5,0.5v3.523L15.56,2.961 c-0.24-0.141-0.545-0.057-0.683,0.184c-0.138,0.239-0.056,0.545,0.183,0.684l2.339,1.352v2.678l-4.729-2.73 c-0.24-0.14-0.545-0.057-0.683,0.184c-0.138,0.239-0.056,0.545,0.183,0.684l5.229,3.02v4.184l-3.837-2.811l0.514,4.729 l-3.621-2.092V6.989c0-0.276-0.224-0.5-0.5-0.5c-0.276,0-0.5,0.224-0.5,0.5v5.462l-2.318-1.34L7.136,8.41 c0-0.277-0.224-0.5-0.5-0.5c-0.276,0-0.5,0.223-0.5,0.5l0.001,2.125L3.084,8.771C2.845,8.63,2.539,8.714,2.401,8.955 C2.263,9.194,2.345,9.5,2.584,9.638L5.636,11.4l-1.839,1.062c-0.239,0.139-0.321,0.443-0.183,0.684 c0.093,0.16,0.261,0.25,0.434,0.25c0.085,0,0.171-0.021,0.25-0.066l2.339-1.351l2.319,1.339l-4.729,2.73 c-0.239,0.139-0.321,0.443-0.183,0.684c0.093,0.16,0.261,0.25,0.434,0.25c0.085,0,0.171-0.021,0.25-0.066l5.23-3.021l3.622,2.091 l-4.352,1.919l4.351,1.919l-3.621,2.09l-5.231-3.018c-0.241-0.138-0.545-0.058-0.683,0.184c-0.138,0.24-0.056,0.545,0.183,0.686 l4.731,2.729l-2.321,1.34l-2.338-1.352c-0.239-0.142-0.545-0.058-0.683,0.184c-0.138,0.238-0.056,0.545,0.183,0.684l1.838,1.062 l-3.05,1.76c-0.239,0.139-0.321,0.443-0.183,0.684c0.093,0.16,0.261,0.25,0.434,0.25c0.085,0,0.171-0.021,0.25-0.065l3.051-1.763 L6.14,27.4c0,0.276,0.224,0.5,0.5,0.5l0,0c0.276,0,0.5-0.225,0.5-0.5l-0.001-2.701l2.322-1.34l-0.002,5.463 c0,0.277,0.224,0.5,0.5,0.5s0.5-0.223,0.5-0.5l0.002-6.041l3.619-2.09l-0.514,4.729l3.837-2.81v4.183l-5.228,3.021 c-0.239,0.139-0.321,0.442-0.183,0.684c0.138,0.236,0.444,0.318,0.683,0.184l4.728-2.73v2.679l-2.339,1.353 c-0.239,0.139-0.321,0.442-0.183,0.684c0.138,0.236,0.444,0.32,0.683,0.184l1.839-1.062V35.3c0,0.274,0.224,0.5,0.5,0.5 s0.5-0.226,0.5-0.5v-3.524l1.841,1.062c0.079,0.046,0.165,0.066,0.25,0.066c0.174,0,0.342-0.09,0.435-0.25 c0.139-0.239,0.057-0.545-0.184-0.684l-2.341-1.354v-2.678l4.729,2.73c0.079,0.046,0.165,0.066,0.25,0.066 c0.174,0,0.342-0.09,0.435-0.25c0.139-0.239,0.057-0.545-0.184-0.684l-5.229-3.021V22.6l3.838,2.811l-0.514-4.729l3.62,2.09v6.039 c0,0.276,0.224,0.5,0.5,0.5c0.275,0,0.5-0.224,0.5-0.5V23.35l2.318,1.34l0.001,2.699c0,0.275,0.225,0.5,0.5,0.5s0.5-0.225,0.5-0.5 l-0.001-2.123l3.053,1.764c0.079,0.045,0.165,0.066,0.25,0.066c0.174,0,0.342-0.09,0.435-0.25 C33.536,26.604,33.454,26.296,33.212,26.16z M20.997,23.259l-2.6-1.901l-0.499-0.363l-0.501,0.365l-2.598,1.9l0.348-3.201 l0.067-0.615l-0.567-0.25l-2.945-1.299l2.946-1.299l0.566-0.25l-0.067-0.616l-0.348-3.2l2.598,1.901l0.5,0.364l0.5-0.365l2.6-1.901 l-0.349,3.201l-0.066,0.616l0.564,0.249l2.946,1.3l-2.944,1.299l-0.566,0.25l0.066,0.615L20.997,23.259z"/>
  </svg>

  <div>Here is some text. It's even wrapped.</div>

</div>
```