# Orbit type chart in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, geometry

I want to create something similar to this. I am going to use d3.js. I have created outer orbit and inner circle. But how to calculate position of outer rings on the outer orbit ?

[image]

The number of outer circles is dynamic.

Comment: Add the code  you tried so far .

Comment: code tried till now. it was from an example on d3.js    
http://jsfiddle.net/tb25p2p5/

Comment: i want to understand logic also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A point at angle theta on the circle whose centre is (x0,y0) and whose radius is r is (x0 + r cos theta, y0 + r sin theta). Now choose theta values evenly spaced between 0 and 2pi.

Reference: [Calculating the position of points in a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300938/calculating-the-position-of-points-in-a-circle)

```
var orbit = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("class", "earthOrbit")
  .attr("r", radii.earthOrbit)
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "#bababa")
  .style("stroke-width", "30");

var circlePositions = getCirclePoints(15, radii.earthOrbit, {
  X: 0,
  Y: 0
});

svg.selectAll(".earth").data(circlePositions)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "earth")
  .style("fill", "white")
  .attr("r", radii.earth)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.cx
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.cy
  })
  .style("stroke", "#bababa")
  .style("stroke-width", "10");
```

```js
var now = d3.time.year.floor(new Date());

var spacetime = d3.select('body');
var width = 960,
  height = 700,
  radius = Math.min(width, height);

var radii = {
  "sun": radius / 6,
  "earthOrbit": radius / 2.5,
  "earth": radius / 32,
  "moonOrbit": radius / 16,
  "moon": radius / 96
};

// Space
var svg = spacetime.append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

// Sun
var sun = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("class", "sun")
  .attr("r", radii.sun)
  //.style("fill", "rgba(255, 204, 0, 1.0)");
  .style("stroke", "#f58c2e")
  .style("stroke-width", "10")
  .style("fill", "none");

// Earth's orbit
var orbit = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("class", "earthOrbit")
  .attr("r", radii.earthOrbit)
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "#bababa")
  .style("stroke-width", "30");

// Current position of Earth in its orbit
var earthOrbitPosition = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radii.earthOrbit + 1)
  .innerRadius(radii.earthOrbit - 1)
  .startAngle(0)
  .endAngle(0);

svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "earthOrbitPosition")
  .attr("d", earthOrbitPosition)
  .style("fill", "rgba(255, 204, 0, 0.75)");


// Time of day
var day = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radii.earth)
  .innerRadius(0)
  .startAngle(0)
  .endAngle(0);

svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "day")
  .attr("d", day)
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + -radii.earthOrbit + ")")
  .style("fill", "rgba(53, 110, 195, 1.0)");


// Current position of the Moon in its orbit
var moonOrbitPosition = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radii.moonOrbit + 1)
  .innerRadius(radii.moonOrbit - 1)
  .startAngle(0)
  .endAngle(0);

svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "moonOrbitPosition")
  .attr("d", moonOrbitPosition)
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + -radii.earthOrbit + ")")
  .style("fill", "rgba(113, 170, 255, 0.75)");

function getCirclePoints(points, radius, center) {
  var circlePositions = [];
  var slice = 2 * Math.PI / points;
  for (var i = 0; i < points; i++) {
    var angle = slice * i;
    var newX = (center.X + radius * Math.cos(angle));
    var newY = (center.Y + radius * Math.sin(angle));
    circlePositions.push({
      cx: newX,
      cy: newY
    });
  }
  return circlePositions;
}

var circlePositions = getCirclePoints(15, radii.earthOrbit, {
  X: 0,
  Y: 0
});
svg.selectAll(".earth").data(circlePositions)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "earth")
  .style("fill", "white")
  .attr("r", radii.earth)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.cx
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.cy
  })
  .style("stroke", "#bababa")
  .style("stroke-width", "10");
```

```css
.earth {}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gilsha :)