# How to draw octagon inside an octagon where both centered in same point?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

How to draw octagon inside an octagon where both centered in same point in turtle using Python?
This what I did so far:

```
import turtle

for i in range(8):
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(360/8)

    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.goto(20, -20)


    turtle.penup()


    for i in range(8):
           turtle.forward(40)
           turtle.right(360/8)
```

Comment: if they are both centered at the same point wont the second octagon just overlap the first?

Comment: They both should be in different sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put the pen down, trace the first pentagon in the first for loop, travel half the distance of the first line and begin your new smaller octagon there

```
import turtle

turtle.pendown()
for i in range(8):
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(360/8)

turtle.forward(50)
for i in range(8):
       turtle.forward(FIGURE OUT WHAT THE NEW DISTANCE IS)
       turtle.right(360/8)
```

if it was important to jump to point 20,-20 and start with octagon 40 length there this would be the version

```
import turtle

turtle.pendown()
for i in range(8):
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(360/8)

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(20, -20)
turtle.pendown()

for i in range(8):
       turtle.forward(40)
       turtle.right(360/8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that [points on a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5300938/190597) are given by the formula

```
x = r * cos(theta)
y = r * sin(theta)
```

where `r` is the radius and `theta` is the angle subtended by the ray extending from the origin to the point and the x-axis. The vertices of an octagon are equally spaced on a circle. So if we choose equally spaced `theta`s from 0 to 2 pi radians, then we'll have the vertices of an octagon:

```
import turtle
from math import pi, cos, sin

def ngon(n, dist, phase, shift=(0,0)):
    theta = 2 * pi / n
    x0, y0 = shift
    turtle.penup()
    x = dist * cos(phase) + x0
    y = dist * sin(phase) + y0
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        x = dist * cos(i*theta + phase) + x0
        y = dist * sin(i*theta + phase) + y0
        turtle.goto(x, y)

def demo_ngon():
    turtle.speed(0.1)
    turtle.width(2.0)
    ngon(8, dist=100, phase=0)
    ngon(8, dist=68, phase=0)
    turtle.mainloop()

demo_ngon()
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
import turtle

for i in range(8):
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(360/8)

turtle.forward(50)
for i in range(8):
       turtle.forward(40)
       turtle.right(360/8)
```